# Recursión con Arrays (java)

Tags: array, recursión

Tengo que decidir el máximo del array desde arr[0] hasta el `index arr[i]` en el método `int maximum( int[] arr, int i )` con `0<=i<arr.length` y no puedo usar ni `for` ni `while`, mi pregunta es como se podria hacer de forma recursiva sin usar el método `math.max` ? 
mi código es:

```
public static int maximum(int[]arr,int i) {     
    if(i == 1) {
      return arr[0];
    }
    return Math.max(arr[i-1],maximum(arr, i-1) ); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Propongo el siguiente metodo maximum:***

```
public static int maximum(int[] arr, int index, int max) {
    int maxCurrent = max;

    if(index < 0 || index >= arr.length) {
        return maxCurrent;
    }

    if(arr[index] > maxCurrent) {
        maxCurrent = arr[index];
    }

    return maximum(arr, index + 1, maxCurrent);
}
```

**Al metodo `maximun` solo se le pasan tres argumentos que son:**

> - El arreglo(arr): Por lo minimo debe de estar instanciado.
> - El indice(index): El cual en cada llamada aumentara en uno, para poder pasar a la siguiente posicion del arreglo a evaluar con el valor del parametro max.
> - El maximo(max): Este en cada llamada llevara o guardara el valor maximo que hasta el momento se ha encontrado en cada llamada.

**Breve explicacion:**

El metodo comienza (`int maxCurrent = max`) guardando una copia del valor maximo hasta el momento encontrado en la variable `maxCurrent`. *(se pudo usar el mismo valor de max, pero por legibilidad de codigo mejor se creo la variable temporal maxCurrent)*

Luego (`index < 0 || index >= arr.length`) se pasa a evaluar el valor del `index`, en la cual se pregunta: que mientras el indice no sea menor a cero ó el indice no sea mayor o igual al limite superior del arreglo, que retorne el valor maximo que hasta el momento se encontro.

Ahora (`arr[index] > maxCurrent`) hay una segunda evaluacion, pero esta vez se evaluara el valor del arreglo actual contra el valor maximo que actualmente se encontro, Si el valor del arreglo es mayor al valor maximo encontrado hasta el momento, entonces quiere decir de que ya la variable `maxCurrent` no contiene el valor maximo, si no el valor de la posicion actual del arreglo.

Al final se vuelve a llamar al metodo `maximum` pasandole el arreglo, pasandole el valor del indice mas un valor de uno y el valor maximo actual que se encontro.

---

> Coloco el codigo completo, donde me tome la libertad de [sobrecargar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobrecarga_(inform%C3%A1tica)) el
>   metodo `maximum`, de esta manera si solo se nesecita saber el valor
>   maximo del arreglo completo se llama a la sobrecarga especifica y
>   listo. (nada de estar pasando parametros adicionales).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 7, 4, 10, 8, 4, 6, 3, 7};

    int max1 = maximum(arr);
    int max2 = maximum(arr, 0, 0);

    System.out.println(max1);
    System.out.println(max2);


    // maximo valor a partir de la posicion 3 del arreglo
    System.out.println(maximum(arr, 3, 0));

    // maximo valor a partir de la posicion 5 del arreglo
    System.out.println(maximum(arr, 5, 0));

    // maximo valor a partir de la posicion 6 del arreglo
    System.out.println(maximum(arr, 6, 0));

    // maximo valor a partir de la posicion 6 del arreglo
    // que sea mayor a 15
    System.out.println(maximum(arr, 6, 15));

    // maximo valor a partir de la posicion 6 del arreglo
    // que sea mayor a 7
    System.out.println(maximum(arr, 6, 7));

    // prueba pasandole un valor negativo al index,
    // y te retorna el valor maximo que le pasaste.
    // System.out.println(maximum(arr, -1, 7));
}

public static int maximum(int[] arr) {
    return maximum(arr, 0, 0);
}

public static int maximum(int[] arr, int index, int max) {
    int maxCurrent = max;

    if(index < 0 || index >= arr.length) {
        return maxCurrent;
    }

    if(arr[index] > maxCurrent) {
        maxCurrent = arr[index];
    }

    return maximum(arr, index + 1, maxCurrent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

De esta manera recorres el array sin nesecidad de un cliclo, la variable j representa el índice del array, luego en cada recursión compruebas si el elemento actual es mayor que el anterior, si es mayor se remplaza, si no continúa el anterior que inicialmente es arr[0], la condición de parada es que el índice j sea igual al tope i, retornas el mayor elemento hasta el momento, si no se llama el método con ++j. Atento que si lo haces con j++, no funciona, ya que j++, utiliza el valor de j en la expresión y luego lo incrementa, mientras que ++j primero incrementa y luego utiliza el valor en la expresión.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       int[]arr={1,2,3,7,4,8};
       int max=maximum(arr,7,0,arr[0]);
       System.out.println (max);
       // la salida para este ejemplo es 7
    }

    public static int maximum(int[]arr,int i,int j,int max) {     
        int maxActual=max;
        if(arr[j]>maxActual){
            maxActual=arr[j];
        }
        if(i == j) {
        return maxActual;
        }
        return maximum(arr,i,++j,maxActual);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

También se podría hacer:

```
public static int maximum(int[] arr, int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i >= arr.length) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    if (i == 0) {
        return arr[0];
    } else {
        int max = maximum(arr, i - 1);
        if (arr[i] > max) {
            return arr[i];
        } else {
            return max;
        }
    }
}
```